# codesign says 'no identity found'

Tags: macos, code-signing

I have a [utility](http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch) that patches the Apple remote control service so it doesn't start iTunes when pressing play.  With OS X 10.8 rcd was signed by Apple.  I found out that I could ad hoc sign the modified rcd to prevent it from crashing, but it seems that some users don't have an identity.

```
$ sudo codesign -f -s - /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd
/System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd: no identity found
```

Does anyone know to generate the ad hoc identity?

Thanks!